# Why can't periods be used in Angular2 selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular

I was trying out the [angular quick start](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) - but felt like using a period in my component's selector, e.g. 'my.app' instead of 'my-app'.

This caused Angular not to load correctly, chrome dev tools claim

> The selector 'my.app' does not exist in the document

My **index.html** body:

```
<body>
  <my.app>Loading...<my.app>
</body>
```

and **app.component.js**:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my.app',
      template: '<h1>[Template] Hello Worlds!</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation related to this.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Because HTML element names can only contain a-z, A-Z and 0-9.  The period is used in CSS selectors to denote a `class`.

Comment: @jmoerdyk If you add it as an answer he can accept it and the question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `my.app` is not a valid HTML element name. HTML element names can only contain a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

The period is used in CSS/jQuery selectors to denote a class. So `my.app` would be the selector for a `my` element with a class of `app` like `<my class='app'>`